# Can ant replace task just deal with files after a timestamp?

Tags: ant, replace, task

The ant replace task is not like copy task which have a overwrite property, copy task can copy files that modifytime is changed.

How can I make replace task just deal with files be changed in copy task?
or save a timestamp somewhere, let replace task just deal with files which modifytime is after the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<replace dir="${dir}" value="that" token="this">
   <include name="**/*.txt"/>
   <date datetime="${timestamp}" when="before"/>
</replace>
```

More infos :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#dateselect
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html